# Postgresql ROUND function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I try to round this query but my result has 10 decimal places. I've tried DECIMAL() function, CAST()ROUND() and its still doesn't work. 
I need 2 decimal places.

```
select type, count(id) filter ( where type ilike 
'private') as "number of applications",
   count(id) filter ( where type ilike 'private' and 
 type ilike 'paid') as "number of paid applications",
(count(id) filter ( where type ilike 'private' and 
status ilike 'paid')
     /round(count(id) filter (where type ilike 'private')) * 
(100)) as "percent of paid applications"
from applications
where type ilike 'private'
group by type
union
select type, count(id) filter ( where type ilike 
'business') as "number of applications",
      count(id) filter ( where type ilike 'private' and 
status ilike 'paid') as "number of paid applications",
      (count(id) filter ( where type ilike 'business' and 
status ilike 'paid')
       /round(count(id) filter (where type ilike 
'business')) * (100)) as "percent of paid applications"
from applications
where type ilike 'business'
group by type
```

Answer (score 0):

`round(yourvalue,2)` should do want you want

e.g. `select round(12.1451124569,2)` a number with 10 decimal precision as the first argument returns `12.15`

Answer (score 0):

You want to round the result.  No need to round the denominator count.

```
...round(count(id) filter ( where type ilike 'business' and status ilike 'paid')
/(count(id) filter (where type ilike 'business')) * (100), 2) 
as "percent of paid applications"
```

Or if that gets a little too confusing you could do it as s sub query and round the result:

```
select t.type, t.count, round(t."percent of paid applications", 2), t.etc from (your huge query here) as t;
```

Comment: Yes, I know, but if I do not do it in the nominative, the result is 0%. whereas when I do what you proposed - * 100), 2 I just get = result, 2 (9.129219219,2)